# How to store course other than dropdown menu and open new textbox put other educations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Model field - degree, institute, percentage these are the model field.

If course is other than dropdown menu so select "Other" and display textbox for enter user education. and when form submit i want to store education in degree column. but now i am not able to handle these two value.

education.html.erb file

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :user_id, "Select User.*" %>
    <% if params[:user_id] != nil %>
      <%= f.select :user_id, :collection => User.where(:id => params[:user_id]).map{|u| ["#{u.firstname}, #{u.lastname}", u.id]} %>
    <% else  %>
      <%  @selected_user_id = EducationInformations.where(:id => params[:id]).pluck(:user_id).first  %>
      <%= f.select :user_id, :collection => User.where(:id => @selected_user_id).map{|u| ["#{u.firstname}, #{u.lastname}", u.id]} %>
    <% end  %>  
  </p>   
  <br/> 
  <% course = ["MCA","BCA","BSC","Engg","Diploma in computer science","Other"] %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :degree, "Select Course.*" %>
    <%= f.select :degree , :collection => (course) %>
  </p>
  <div id="other_edu">
    <br/>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :other_degree, "Enter your course" %>
      <%= f.text_field :other_degree , :id => "other_course", :onblur => "getCourse()" %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :institute, "Institute*" %>
    <%= f.text_field :institute %>
  </p>
  <br/>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :percentage, "Grade/Percentage" %>
    <%= f.text_field :percentage %>
  </p>
```

---

```
javascript

$(document).ready(function() {

    var select = document.getElementById('education_informations_degree');
    var other_course = document.getElementById('other_course');
    $('#other_edu').hide(); 

        select.onchange = function() {
            var selected_course =  select.value;
            if (selected_course == "Other")
            {
                $('#other_edu').show(); 
            }else{
                $('#other_edu').hide(); 
            }

        }

    });

function getCourse() {
        var x = document.getElementById("other_course"); 
        var select = document.getElementById('education_informations_degree');
        select.value = x.value;
        console.log(x.value);
    }
```

---

```
 Model
                                                                                            class EducationInformations < ActiveRecord::Base
      unloadable
       attr_accessible :user_id, :degree, :institute, :passing_year, :country, :university, :percentage

        validates :degree, presence: true
        validates :passing_year, presence: true
        validates :university, presence: true
        validates :institute, presence: true

    end
```

---

```
Controller 

    def create
        @edu_info = EducationInformations.new(educational_params)

            if @edu_info.save
                #flash[:notice] = 'Vote saved.'
                redirect_to @edu_info
            else
                render "new"
            end     

    end

private

    def educational_params
        params.require(:education_informations).permit(:user_id, :degree, :institute, :passing_year, :country, :university, :percentage)
    end
```

Comment: @Pavan Can you help me for this problem?

Comment: can you put your controller in here? Do you use Strong Params? Your question is not very clear. Where is "education"? by education, do you mean `course` that you defined in your view?

Comment: @Mr H Now you can see my controller.

Comment: If you use the StrongParrams and passing them to your model can you please let me know why you  would be using `attr_accessible` in your model? You will have access to them when you pass it to the model from your controller. `@edu_info` is instantiated with the params so you don't need a `Getter` and `Setter` (`attr_accessible`) in your model.

Comment: Hello Everyone I fixed this issue using javascript. Thank you for response.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed this problem when user select value from dropdown list so I set value as textbox value. If I select "Other" item so display textbox and whatever user can enter so I send value of text. I know this is not best way but I think this solution handle my problem.

---

View code

```
 <% course = ["MCA","BCA","BSC","Engg","Diploma in computer science","Other"] %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag "select_degree", "Select Course *" %>
    <%= select_tag "select_degree" , options_for_select(course) %>
  </p>
  <div id="other_edu">
    <br/>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :degree, "Enter your course *" %>
      <%= f.text_field :degree  %>
    </p>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :institute, "Institute *" %>
    <%= f.text_field :institute %>
  </p>
  <br/>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :percentage, "Grade/Percentage " %>
    <%= f.text_field :percentage %>
  </p>
```

---

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var select = document.getElementById('select_degree');
    var other_course = document.getElementById('education_informations_degree');
    $('#other_edu').hide(); 

    select.onchange = function() {

        var selected_course =  select.value;
        if (selected_course == "Other")
        {
            $('#other_edu').show(); 
        }else{
            $('#other_edu').hide(); 
            other_course.value = select.value;
        }

    }

});
```